# Parse Russian XML retrieves NullPointerException SAXParser

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using SAXParser to parse an XML which contains russian characters.
The XML looks like this:

```
   ...
   <exercise>
     <ID>2</ID>
     <training_types_id>1</training_types_id>
     <Name>Тройки</Name>
     <last_modified>0000-00-00 00:00:00</last_modified>
     <del_check>0</del_check>
   </exercise>
   ...
```

The app crashes on this code (and online on the node "Name" which contains russian symbols):

```
String exerciseNameValue = exerciseNameElement.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

The server encodes data this way:

```
        if (is_null($DOMDocument)) {
        $DOMDocument =new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $DOMDocument->formatOutput = true;
        $this->xml_encode($mixed, $DOMDocument, $DOMDocument);
        return $DOMDocument->saveXML();
```

I receive the data this way:

```
HttpEntity entity = res.getEntity();
websiteData = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
```

Parse it this way:

```
    private static Document ParseXMLString(String xmlString) {

    // fix encoding problem
    xmlString = xmlString.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", "");

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db;
    Document doc = null;

    try {
        InputSource inStream = new InputSource(); 
        inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
        //inStream.setEncoding("UTF8");

        db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(inStream);

    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return doc;
}
```

Dawn error:

```
03-21 06:12:09.227: W/System.err(12256): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-21 06:12:09.228: W/System.err(12256):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 06:12:09.228: W/System.err(12256):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-21 06:12:09.229: W/System.err(12256):    at com.ms.mastersportApp.parsers.AppParser.inParseData(AppParser.java:58)
03-21 06:12:09.229: W/System.err(12256):    at com.ms.mastersportApp.synchronization.Synchronization.SynchronizeDown(Synchronization.java:165)
03-21 06:12:09.229: W/System.err(12256):    at com.ms.mastersportApp.threads.SyncThread.doInBackground(SyncThread.java:131)
03-21 06:12:09.230: W/System.err(12256):    at com.ms.mastersportApp.threads.SyncThread.doInBackground(SyncThread.java:1)
03-21 06:12:09.230: W/System.err(12256):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
03-21 06:12:09.230: W/System.err(12256):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-21 06:12:09.231: W/System.err(12256):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-21 06:12:09.231: W/System.err(12256):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
03-21 06:12:09.231: W/System.err(12256):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-21 06:12:09.232: W/System.err(12256):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-21 06:12:09.232: W/System.err(12256):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-21 06:12:09.232: W/System.err(12256): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 06:12:09.233: W/System.err(12256):    at com.ms.mastersportApp.parsers.XmlParser.ParseXMLExercisesStr(XmlParser.java:179)
03-21 06:12:09.233: W/System.err(12256):    at com.ms.mastersportApp.parsers.XmlParser.ParseXMLExercises(XmlParser.java:131)
```

Comment: Your stack trace shows that the NPE is at `ParseXMLExercisesStr(XmlParser.java:179)`. Why have you not shown us that code? Look there, that's where the exception is coming from.

Comment: Side note: you "server code" does not look like Java... and "fix encoding problem" probably indicates that whatever "XML" you create is not really valid XML ...

Comment: This is a dom parser ?

Comment: String exerciseNameValue = exerciseNameElement.getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); this is ParseXMLExercisesStr. I told is crashing there. All the other code is working well. Crashes only when the same code meets russian chars.

Comment: Server code is PHP. I'm using an internal PHP class to format the output xml. Why do you mean that is not valid ?